# Get a state from checkbox to div

Tags: jquery, css, forms, checkbox

I need to get a state from checkbox to my div. The div is wrapping the checkbox.

```
<div id="checkWrapper">
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Something like that. And when user clicks the checkbox and it gets checked state I would need to get some class to #checkWrapper div. Class can be anything, maybe something like "checked".

Is it possible with jquery? Is it easy to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector with [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see if it found any matches, like this:

```
var is_checked = $("#checkWrapper :checkbox:checked").length > 0;
```

For the click handler you can do this:

```
$("#checkWrapper :checkbox").change(function() {
  $("#checkWrapper").toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
});
```

This would add the `checked` class when it was checked, remove it when it's not.  If you need to do this with many elements, use a class like `class="checkWrapper"` with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), like this:

```
$(".checkWrapper :checkbox").change(function() {
  $(this).closest(".checkWrapper").toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Does the change have some problems with IE? I think I might have had some problems with it earlier. I might remember wrong aswell.. so I'll give it a go.

Comment: @penissiomo - `change` had issues in IE with bubbling in older (pre 1.4.2) versions of jQuery, it isn't an issue now...and none of the above code relies on bubbling anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#checkWrapper :checkbox').live('change', function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: This is a very bad way to do it, it's an expensive initial selector, doesn't allow for other classes, and is very inefficient at getting the `checked` property - the edited version doesn't really address the main issues.

Comment: yeah, my first pass was not the best way, but i've cleaned it up

Comment: using `.closest()` may not be what he wants... in his HTML example it appears that `.parents()` is more what he wants

Comment: It's an ID selector so there's a single element, there's no need for either given his example.  `.parents()` will get *all* parent elements.

Comment: @nick i think maybe just `parent()` then would be best, assuming his ids change and are unique